# Force Automapper to set DateTimeKind.Utc on all DateTimes using Project

Tags: c#, automapper

I am looking for a way to get `AutoMapper` to specify the `DateTimeKind` on all my dates to `Utc` when using `ProjectTo`.  I have looked around and found some solutions but none seem to work:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(i => DateTime.SpecifyKind(i, DateTimeKind.Utc));
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing(i => DateTime.SpecifyKind(i.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

Or

```
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>().ProjectUsing(i => new DateTime(i.Year, i.Month, i.Day, i.Hour, i.Minute, i.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc));
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ProjectUsing(i => new DateTime(i.Value.Year, i.Value.Month, i.Value.Day, i.Value.Hour, i.Value.Minute, i.Value.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

Or

```
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>().ConstructProjectionUsing(i => new DateTime(i.Year, i.Month, i.Day, i.Hour, i.Minute, i.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc));
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConstructProjectionUsing(i => new DateTime(i.Value.Year, i.Value.Month, i.Value.Day, i.Value.Hour, i.Value.Minute, i.Value.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

I also tried this but after some digging in the docs it seems ResolveUsing won't work when using `ProjectTo`

```
cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(map => (map.SourceType == typeof(DateTime?) || map.SourceType == typeof(DateTime)), (map, expression) =>
{
    expression.ResolveUsing(o =>
        {
            var date = o as DateTime;
            DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return date;
        });
});
```

Am I doing it the wrong way or it there a better way to try and achieve this?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49706/Using-AutoMapper-s-Custom-Formatters